# HAAR training hangs in 7th stage

Tags: opencv, image-processing, haar-classifier

My Haar training gets hung in the 7th stage. Could someone please help to understand why and how I can get rid of such hung?

I use only 10 stages and have around 500 images.This is my training command:

```
opencv_traincascade -data data_50x50 -vec samples_50x50.vec -bg neg_70x70.dat -numPos 495 -numNeg 570 -numStages 10 -w 20 -h 20 -featureType HAAR -mode ALL -precalcValBufSize 1024 -precalcIdxBufSize 1024  -minHitRate 0.999 -maxFalseAlarmRate 0.1 -maxWeakCount 1000
```

Till 6th stage it runs fast (<5 hours), then in 7th stage, I am waiting days:
I can see that FA is decreasing till 6th stage.

```
+----+---------+---------+
END>
Training until now has taken 0 days 0 hours 27 minutes 11 seconds.

===== TRAINING 6-stage =====
<BEGIN
POS count : consumed   495 : 495
NEG count : acceptanceRatio    570 : 1.59311e-06
Precalculation time: 4
+----+---------+---------+
|  N |    HR   |    FA   |
+----+---------+---------+
|   1|        1|        1|
+----+---------+---------+
|   2|        1|        1|
+----+---------+---------+
|   3|        1| 0.166667|
+----+---------+---------+
|   4|        1|        0|
+----+---------+---------+
END>
Training until now has taken 0 days 4 hours 2 minutes 32 seconds.

===== TRAINING 7-stage =====
<BEGIN
POS count : consumed   495 : 495
```

Remains in such stage for ages (>2 days)

Thanks

Comment: is there any NEG count happening (but very very slow)?

Comment: probably there are no NEG samples left after stage 6. Try training with same parameters numStages 7 to use your current trained classifier, of you like to.

Comment: Does it mean that I need to incease the number of my negative images?? When I set numStages to 6, than the cascasde.xml is being generated withouth any issues.

Comment: numStages 7 should work too, since stage number starts with 0. Yes, I would suggest to use more samples.

Comment: If you see NEG number going up after a while (might even be half an hour) it means it's still training. But the problem might not be negative samples running out (although 500 is really really small), but the fact that you use `-minHitRate 0.999 -maxFalseAlarmRate 0.1 -maxWeakCount 1000`. As I told you [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45798288/ideas-to-improve-haar-training-results) these will take ages even if you use LBP, let alone HAAR.